# Tablesorter Custom Filter Function - Full Table Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, tablesorter

I have a tablesorter, with 2 filter Columns. The first Filter works as a drop down and has no issues right now. The second filter is intended to be a **full table search and filter** mechanism.

That is to say, **even though it is associated with the computer column, it should return results for child rows as well**
[image]

The Computer Filter should respond to **all child rows.** For instance, if I searched for **z840,** , only Computers with **Model z840** should appear.

However, I have a **custom secondary filter mechanism by request**  The gauge at the top, works as a filter for **workgroup**

However, If I am filtered in a workgroup, and use the Computer Filter, it ignores the custom hidden rows, and searches against any row in the table. (Child Row Searching works fine).

My Question is, Is there a way to overwrite the functionality of the filter, to ignore any rows that are already satisfying some condition IE: `$(row).hasClass('hide')`

I have tried using `filter_functions` but every result ends up searching on **computer name** only

I am using Jinja Templating so it was a little hard to get a fiddle up and running but here is a sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/brianz820/856bzzeL/813/

Sort by wg02 (at top, no results), and then use the computer filter to search for say, 3.3. No results show up, but once you delete the search, the original workgroup filter is removed.

On my production copy, even typing 3.3 would have returned results for any workgroup, ignoring the filter.

There may be lots of extraneous code on Fiddle, just wanted to get a working version up

Thanks for reading, Goal to maintain free form child searching and filtering on filter selection, but maintain external hidden rows.

if there is any more required information please let me know

Comment: Can you provide a few more rows in the demo and explain what the "Type" filter is supposed to target.

Comment: Hi @Mottie, thanks for reply I updated the fiddle with some more data. http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/821/     In reality I am using a templating engine. I also added in a tab for All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you meant, but the `hideRows` function can be simplified by using the filter widget ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/823/)):

```
function hideRows() {
    var $table = $('.tablesorter'),
    filters = $.tablesorter.getFilters( $table );
  filters[2] = selected === 'All' ? '' : selected;
  $.tablesorter.setFilters( $table, filters );
}
```

Comment: Ill give it a shot, thanks. What I really want is for the `wg01, wg02` buttons to stay even when working in the search box

Comment: They will stay, unless the user presses the filter reset button. That `hideRows` function can then be called at any time to add that filter back.. it won't interfere with other filter settings.

Comment: Thanks will work it out when I get back at it. Thanks Mottie!

Comment: So, seems I needed to update to a new version of TableSorter for the `getFilters` function, and now my filtering widget stuff wont work (but sorting and child rows still work). Digging in but I had thought pointing the script src to the 2.25.2 version of `jquery.tablesorter.js` and `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` would have worked with out any code change.... edit: also updated to jquery-1.12.0..... I can see the filters applied with `console.log` but they are not being hidden